# How to do a fast convert of a .xls (MS Excel) file to .csv

Tags: linux, centos, php, csv, javascript

How can I do a fast convert of excel to csv? I have tried with php, perl, JavaScript. but it takes too much time. For example, for a 5MB file it will take 3-5 minutes.

Answer (score 5):

libreoffice offers this option, I cannot tell about resource use, though:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv $filename(s) --outdir $outdir
```

`--outdir` is optional and will be the current working dir if not specified, batch mode is possible by simply specifying multiple files.

Comment: I have libreoffice installed.  I run the above and get exactly nothing - no new file, no error, just back to the prompt.  Tried this ... libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file://myfile.xls --headless --convert-to csv  ... and then I get "javaldx failed" and "Error in function createSettingsDocument".  Wish gnumeric was availiable for Centos7.

Comment: @JosephK "I have libreoffice installed. I run the above and get exactly nothing". I had the same issue, after closing all LibreOffice windows the command worked.

Answer (score 3):

#### Fedora/Redhat/CentOS:

```
yum install gnumeric
```

#### Debian/Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install gnumeric
```

---

```
ssconvert myexcel.xlsx myexcel.csv
```

Reference:

1. [Gnumeric](http://www.gnumeric.org/?ckattempt=1)
2. [man ssconvert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ssconvert.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

Gnumeric is a third party package, it can be downloaded from their site.

Yum install gnumeric won't work on RedHat servers.

Comment: Or centos - and the gnumeric site says to get it from your OS's repos.  I searched about 500 search results without finding one that has it for Centos 7.